# Naming Folders using Clipboard

Tags: macos, applescript, copy-paste

Is there a script that allows one to insert text from the clipboard into the name field of a new folder? I would like to name a new folder or change the name of a folder using the last text clip.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need a script for this?

1. Press ⌘⇧N to create a new folder.

   The folder name is already highlighted.
2. Press ⌘V to paste the current clipboard.
3. Press ↩︎.

…or for current folders…

1. Press ↩︎ to rename the folder.

   The folder name is already highlighted.
2. Press ⌘V to paste the current clipboard.
3. Press ↩︎.